# Sprites quality is very bad in Game window in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]
I have created a 2D project. The images I used for sprites are all with high resolution. However I do not know what settings I have changed today, the sprites in game window started look terrible when I tested the game(good quality in scene window). And this happens to all of the projects I created earlier. But when I build the exe file to play, the graphics look all good with original quality. Could anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: can you attach a screenshot of both the scene view and game view?

Comment: @Ido Ben Shalom, Please check my newly added picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scale back the game view to 1x and change the size of your camera instead or set your sprites to their original size if they have been resized
[image]

Comment: You can check the Mip Map generation option on your textures. The ideia is to change the texture quality depending on the camera distance. I imagine that you don't want this enabled on your game

Comment: @Bruno Pinheiro, Ido Ben Shalom's solution works for my issue. I just happened to changed my camera size which leaded to my problem.

Comment: @jeep - I know. I just didn't explain well what I was trying to do with my comment. I had a similar problem when I was testing on a physical device. The textures were rendered with a low quality. This is just a tip in case you face something like this! :)

Comment: @Bruno Pinheiro, Thank you for pointing out this potential issue:)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Retina screen, [make sure you uncheck the](https://youtu.be/4SFf3oXw9MU) following checkbox.

[image]

**[Watch this screencast](https://youtu.be/4SFf3oXw9MU)**

Answer (score 0):

For 2D game also make sure Projection property in Camera component is set to Orthographic